# Need the original length of the text when ngrm analyzer is applied

Tags: elasticsearch

When Bi-gram analyzer is applied to the Name field and I check `doc[Name].value.length()` it returns 2, but I want the original length of the Name. 
Example `Infotech = 8` need to return 8

```
"mappings": {
        "Data": {
            "properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "type":     "text",
                    "analyzer": "bigrams" ,
                    "similarity": "scripted_tfidf",
                     "fielddata": true,
                     "fields": {
                           "length": { 
                              "type":     "token_count",
                               "analyzer": "standard"
                                 }
                     }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a field of keyword type in the mapping because it will not be analyzed like this :

```
            "fields": {

                   "keyword": { 

                          "type":"keyword"

                    }
            }
```

then you can get the real length using :

```
             doc['Name.keyword'].value.length()
```